# How to send a self-defined cryptocurrency in ethereum?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereum-classic

I'm new to this and I have a question regarding the following case:

suppose I defined and deployed a coin A, so coin A publicly exists in the network. Now suppose there is another contract called "conference", and it requires coin A (instead of ether) to buy a ticket. I do have some balance in A's mapping(address --> uint) balance, then given the fact that A is already deployed, how can I send some amount of coin A to conference contract address?

I'm confused since I only know how to send ether by calling address.send(contract_address). Is there a programmatic way for self-defined currency? Thanks.

I know a indirect way to do that: I transfer some amount of A of my account to the conference address by calling A.transferFrom(myaddress, conference), then upon receiving the transaction, the conference organizer calls conference.updateBalance(myaddress, 1).

But is there a direct way to achieve that? i.e. I call conference.buy(uint amount), both balance in A's contract and conference's contract get updated.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Some tokens support [`approveAndCall`](https://github.com/CurrencyTycoon/eth-hodler/issues/2) function. Where the contract is authorized to transfer an amount of tokens from the sender account, and the method `receiveApproval` is called immediately in the receiving contract where the `transfer` can be done.

There's a new proposal know as [ERC223](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223), that defines the method `tokenFallback` will be called to complete the transference.

I've seen several ICOs use `approveAndCall`, ER223 is pretty new and still under review. This is still a work in progress.